# How to improve write performance in DolphinDB?

Tags: performance, dolphindb

I am performing various computations on DolphinDB, the speed are pretty good enough. But I am having an roadblock with the write performance in DolphinDB because my data have thousands of columns, it takes a few seconds to write 100 records. How can I improve it?

Comment: I would expect (like other databases) you need to use a transaction open the transaction add thousands of records then commit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cache engine in DolphinDB? This should work for your case. To enable cache engine, please add one line setup in configuration file as follows

```
//in unit of GB
chunkCacheEngineMemSize = 2
```